# Finding the largest number in a vector which is smaller than specific value

Tags: r

I want to find the largest grade of the failed subjects for students in R. I have written this function which works fine but it looks more like java code than R as it is traversing through vectors using loops instead of using special functions for that purpose in R. would you please suggest an alternative solution

```
grades <- c(62, 100, 45, 40, 46, 55, 56, 70)

largestFail <- function(grades){
  location <- -1
  faildFound <- FALSE

  for(i in 1:length(grades)){
    if(grades[i] < 50){
      if(!faildFound) location <- i
      if(grades[i] > grades[location]) location <- i
      faildFound <- TRUE
    }
  }
  return (location)
}
print (grades) # 5
```

Comment: the desired output is 46 the fifth location

Comment: Is your desired output 5 (for the fifth position), or 46? If it's 5, then PoGibas' solution below does what you want. If it's 46, see my version instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works fine:

```
max(grades[grades < 50])
```

You subset the `grades` vector to those values under 50, and then extract the maximum of it.

If you need detailed understanding, you can evaluate the parts separately:

- `grades < 50` returns a logical vector which is `TRUE` for all values under 50
- `grades[grades < 50]` then is a vector of all values under 50
- Finally, wrap `max()` around this vector to find the highest failing grade

If you want to return -1 when no student failed, something like this should do the job:

```
grades <- c(60, 70, 80)

if(any(grades < 50)){
  return(max(grades[grades < 50])
)
} else {
  return(-1)
}
```

A shorter, but less clear, solution, would be to just append -1 to your vector of grades:

```
grades <- c(60, 70, 80)
grades <- c(grades, -1)
max(grades[grades < 50])
```

Comment: The PoGibas's solution finds the locations using which function but the problem of both methods is that they do not consider situations with no failed subjects for students wich should return -1 or 0 instead of an error

Comment: Returning 0 if no student failed might not be a good idea, since you would also get 0 if only one student failed with a score of 0. Then you wouldn't know which of theses cases happened.

Comment: OK then I think it is better to return -1 than throwing an error

Answer (score 3):

Another way, using `which.max` but replacing the values above the threshold by `NA` prior to the call:

```
which.max(replace(grades, grades>=50, NA))
#[1] 5
```